# how I change the frame data into time series?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, decomposition

I have a daily rainfall data for 36 years. I want to analyze the time series, but my data is still in the form of frame data, how I change the frame data into time series. My data is a variable, how to unify the year number with the date and month, so the data is only in one column

Comment: You may check `?paste`, `?ts` `?as.Date`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a time series package for that, such as `fpp` i.e. `install.packages('fpp')`. Since you don't give an example code, I can't really help you properly with it but it's quite easy.

`ts(your_data, start =, frequency = )` At `start =` you put the year or month where you'd start and at `frequency =` you'd put e.g. 36 since you talk about 36 years.

You might want to check out https://robjhyndman.com/. He has an online (free) book available that walks you through the use of his package as well as providing useful information with respect to time series analysis.

Hope this helps.